# how do I create a mySQL user with hash('sha256', $salt . $password)?

Tags: mysql, hash, passwords, salt

I must be missing something.

I want to set up a database user account for select-only transactions but mysql is not letting me choose the hash method for a password on creating a user account.

this fails:

```
GRANT SELECT ON myDB.* TO 'selectuser'@'localhost' 
IDENTIFIED BY hash('sha256', 'salted-myfakelongrandompasswordstring');
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'hash('sha256', 'salted-myfakelongrandompasswordstring')' at line 1

this passes:

```
GRANT SELECT ON myDB.* TO 'selectuser'@'localhost' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'salted-myfakelongrandompasswordstring';
```

I checked the phpinfo page and the sha256 hash engine is already enabled.

is there a way to change the default hashing algorithm for mysql, or is the syntax just incorrect on my SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you shouldn't use your own password-hashing for MySQL authentication.

MySQL 5.x uses its own hashing function ([`PASSWORD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password)), which produces a 41-byte hex string (based on applying SHA1 to the input twice).  Unfortunately, a salt is not used.

If you were able to use `GRANT` in the manner you show in your question, then MySQL would apply its `PASSWORD()` function to the string output of the `hash()` function.  Subsequently, when you want to log in, you would have to enter the 256-bit hash of your password, for it to match what is in the MySQL authentication database.

Also, MySQL supports the [`SHA2()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2) family of hash functions as of MySQL 5.5.

The [`hash()`](http://php.net/hash) function is something you're probably remembering from PHP.  It is not part of MySQL.

---

Re your comment:  Typically MySQL authentication is totally separate from user account authentication in a given web app (this is best practice for several reasons).

Yes, you need to hardcode the username/password for MySQL authentication for your web app.  Could be in, but even better would be a config file.  Of course, put these outside the web root.

When a user needs to log in, compute the [`hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) of their input password, combined with the [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) value on record for their account.  Then compare this to the hash stored in the database for that user.  In pseudocode:

```
$salt = $db->query("SELECT salt FROM Accounts WHERE account_name = ?", 
    $input_account_name);

$password_hash = hash('sha256', $salt + $input_password)

$is_password_correct = $db->query("SELECT password_hash = ? 
    FROM Accounts WHERE account_name = ?",
    $password_hash, $input_account_name);
```

Comment: so best practice would be...
create database user accounts via the second query method "IDENTIFIED BY ...<literal password>", let mySQL hash that password in the background, then hard code the <literal password> string into a class which is stored outside of the web root.  then for actual human user account passwords, hash those with sha256 in code before passing the hashed literal string to mySQL --- which will then re-hash the hashed string... wait, that last bit sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This [documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html) seems to indicate that sha256 is not implemented in MySQL:

> Also, regarding the mentioned exploit
>   of sha1, there are stronger versions
>   like sha256, sha384, sha512 etc. but
>   mysql does not implement them; they
>   would have to be implemented in code.

Comment: SHA2 family of hash functions are supported in MySQL 6.0.5.  I contributed the patch for this!  :-)

Answer (score -1):

...IDENTIFIED BY hash('your_password','256'). This will cause MySQL to hash your hashed password ;-)